# How to set the selected value of Html.DropDownListFor when the model property has value and select the optionLabel when property is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I want my dropdown to automatically select the optionLabel if my model property is null. But also automatically select the value of my property if it has value.

What is happening to me is that my dropdownlist always select the optionlabel whether my model property has or has no value.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SportsId, new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData[ViewDataKeys.SportList], "Value", "Text"),"---",null)
```

thanks!